# Wrong itemValue with <form:select> and <form:options> using Spring-MVC

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a collection of objects that populate a form:select. I'm using Spring-MVC and JSP. My objects have only two properties: "id" and "name".

The code of my select:

```
<form:select path="something.id">
    <form:option value="-" label="-- Select --"/>
    <form:options items="${objectList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/></form:select>
```

The problem is: doesn´t matter the values of the id properties in my objects in objectList, the values in the options only get his values auto-generated in a sequential way: 0, 1, 2, 3... Below the code generated:

```
<select id="something.id" name="something.id">
    <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1">TEST1</option>
    <option value="2">TEST2</option>
    <option value="3">TEST3</option>
</select>
```

The correct should be (for example):

```
<select id="something.id" name="something.id">
    <option value="-">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="7">TEST1</option>
    <option value="15">TEST2</option>
    <option value="23">TEST3</option>
</select>
```

I've already verified the values in client-side and they are correct. But the values in options are always generated sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, it´s a feature of HDIV.

A6 (Sensitive data exposure) : HDIV offers a confidentially property to all data generated at sever side. That is to say, HDIV replace original parameter values generated at server side by relative values (0,1,2,4, etc.) that avoid exposing critical data to the client side.

Reference: http://www.hdiv.org/hdiv-documentation-single/doc.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form:select path="selectName">
    <form:option value="0" label="Select an Option" />
    <form:options items="${nameOfList}" />
</form:select>
```

reference 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/

Comment: Tried this, yet the same result, when I use the "-", he turns this on "0"... When I put the "0", still don´t take in consideration my own ids, he generates sequentially.

Comment: A detail, objectList is a java.util.List, not a Map. Can this be the problem?